# How to handle a connection properly with jooq?

Tags: oracle, kotlin, session, connection, jooq

I am getting a lot of inactive sessions in the database which not only take up all the resources but also cause the database to crash occasionally requiring me to restart it.

I am using jooq with kotlin, and this is how I establish a connection.

```
@Component
class EstDBConnection(private val cfg: DatabaseConfig, private val jooqExecuteListener: PromJooqExecuteListener) {

    init {
        cfg.migrateFlyway()
    }

    fun <T> acquire(f: (DSLContext) -> T): T {
        return DSL.using(DriverManager.getConnection(cfg.url, cfg.username, cfg.password), SQLDialect.ORACLE10G).use {
            jooqExecuteListener.attach(it)
            f(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never closing the connections that you're creating. Please use a connection pool (e.g. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)) to manage your connections. Unless your writing a simple batch script, or some proof of concept, you should never resort to using `DriverManager.getConnection` directly

Comment: @VladyslavMaksyk: No, but I can recommend a tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp, https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling

Comment: What do you mean by using directly, should it be enclosed in try-catch statement?

Comment: If you do use it (`DriverManager`) directly, then yes, you need `try-with-resources` (not just try-catch) to make sure the connection is closed again. But what you probably really need is a connection pool, because connecting to Oracle takes a bit of time, you want to share those resources among your threads. Take your time to read up on these concepts (resource management and connection pools). These are *very* important concepts, especially when working with databases.